# How to build a dynamic aura blade type of power?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, hero-lab

A player of mine wants to play a Sword master and sword collector type of character. I want it to build the power, if possible, with hero-lab (since is the standard in the group). The general idea is that the character can use most of his damage related powers without the swords but not as efficient as if he had one. For example, imagine a PL 10 character with an strength of 5, and the following power

Aura blade

- **Strength-effect: Extra**: Reach 5 (melee, 5pp).

This would let the char to use his fist, for example, to do a type of Aura attack with some reach. But my problem is how do I build that, when he is using a sword, the Extra reach is increased to 10. Something like:

Aura blade

- **(A) Strength-effect: Extra:** Reach 5 (melee, 5pp).
- **Strength-effect: Extra:** Reach 3 (melee, 3pp), Stacks with (A). **Flaw:** Power-loss (Not using a sword-type weapon, -1pp)

But I have no idea how to build the second part in Herolab or if that is correct using the rules of M&M 3e at all.

Comment: Since you specifically asked for Hero Lab help, there is a Stacks With +0 modifier in Hero Lab, but I honestly am not certain if it stacks modifiers as well as ranks. And, FWIW, despite nick012000 being correct that, generally, Power Loss is a Complication, there are examples of a Quirk (-1 Flat Flaw basically, used to be a Drawback in 2E) of requiring certain materials to use a power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power loss does not result in a decrease in Power Points cost in Mutants and Masterminds 3e; instead, it gives you a Hero Point when it becomes relevant. However, in this case, you could model the power in question using the Easily Removable modifier, which would.

The easiest way to do this would be to use Strength-based Damage with Reach 8 and Easily Removable to represent the use of his sword, then take an Alternate Effect for the reduced effect when not using the sword.

Comment: Reach 8? Why does it need to be 40 feet long? It's a sword.

Comment: ValhallaGH More than a 40 feet long sword is more like an air punch or cut. The size of the sword doesn't increase at all.